# How to list/delete utility networks in a feature dataset

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, utility-network

I have  a Utility network inside a geodatabase that I'm trying to delete using arcpy.
I've managed to use the list functions to identify feature datasets, tables and feature classes but I can't seem to find a function to identify the UtilityNetwork.

The path to the utility network is something like this: mygdb.gdb/MyFeatureDataset/UtilityNetwork
The idea is to do the following:

```
env.workspace = AssetPackage.gdb
                     
ds_list = arcpy.ListDatasets()
for ds in ds_list:
    for un in arcpy.ListUtilityNetwork(ds):
        arcpy.deleteUtilityNetwork(un)
```

As far as I know there's no way to list the utility networks and delete them using Python?
I'm happy to take any suggestions on this - The utility network has a static name/URL so I wouldn't necessarily need to read this, just declare the utility network path and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the utility network is  being stored as a dataset.
I used the following code to delete it:

```
import arcpy  
from arcpy import env
    env.workspace = "/Mygdb.gdb/myfeaturedataset"       
    fc_list = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    tables = arcpy.ListTables()
    ds_list = arcpy.ListDatasets()

    for ds in ds_list:
        print(ds)
        arcpy.management.Delete(ds)
        print(ds + ' deleted')
```

Comment: You appear to have created two accounts. Please use these instructions to merge them: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 0):

To identify if a dataset is a Utility Network, you can use `arcpy.Describe()` to check if the `dataType` is `"UtilityNetwork"`.

You can also filter what datasets to list with `arcpy.ListDatasets()` by providing a `feature_type` value.

Example:

```
utility_networks = arcpy.ListDatasets(feature_type="UtilityNetwork")
```

[Reference 1](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/utility-network-properties.htm), [Reference 2](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/listdatasets.htm)